# How to remove unselected options from drop-down lists within a table in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, typescript

I need to export several tables to excel, I have a component that is always in all the other components and has the function of exporting, in each component I have a table with id 'table' which will be exported.

The problem I have now is that I have inputs within the tables and drop-down lists created with ngFor, but the data entered for the input is not taken by the excel and for the drop-down lists, the function obtains all the options and I need to have only the selected one.

My English is not good, I hope you understood

Solve the inputs by replacing them with the selected value but trying to eliminate unselected options with jQuery, The drop-down list always eliminates all options because it does not detect the selected option.

At this moment I do not know how to do it with Typescript.

```
export() {
{
  const myTable = document.getElementById('table');
  const myClone = myTable.cloneNode(true);

  // Delete options unselected
  $($(myClone).find('select')).each((index, element) => {
    $(element).find('option').not(':selected').remove();
  });

  // Replace input for value
  $($(myClone).find('input')).each((index, element) => {
    $(element).replaceWith(element.value);
  });

  const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(myClone);
  const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');

  /* save to file */
  XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'SheetJS.xlsx');
 }
}
```

I hope to find a way to eliminate these options or if it is easier to find another library that allows me to export to excel with all the functionality I need

Comment: Isn't that already TypeScript?

Comment: You should not be using jQuery with Angular at all costs. Use Angular.

Comment: @Edric I was referring to what I did in jquery, that is to do with typescript.

Comment: As @theblindprophet says, I should try to use only Angular, so I will create a service to obtain the ElementRef table and get this nativeElement, I will bring an update soon with those changes but the problem is that I can not identify the text or the value of the option selected with nativeElement because drop down were created with ngFor and nativeElement detects the default value like selected, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the functionality I needed using jquery

```
// Delete option unselected
$($(myClone).find('select')).each((i, element) => {
  const valueSelected = $(element).attr('ng-reflect-model');
  $($(element).find('option')).each((index, item) => {
    if (item.value !== valueSelected) {
      $(item).remove();
    }
  });
});
```

At the moment this method is being functional, it is best to use elementRef from TypeScript so that will be the next step.

I hope I have helped someone with this.